# Clone one github repo and modify them, then can I share with other using github?

Tags: git, github

For the class project, I am cloning one of repos from Github and modify them.

Can I share this code with other members in this project?

I tried to make new repo and push the code into the new repo. However, it creates some module and does not work well.

Could you give me some comments?

Thanks !

Comment: *Can I share this code with other members in this project?* commit & push it?

Comment: You do seem confused. Do the repository you cloned from on GitHub belong to you or any of your groupmates ? In a nutshell, you can always make edits locally, but can only push to repositories that give you the right to (ie. a repository you own).

Comment: Thanks. 

What I need to do is removing .git in the directory what I cloned and re-create new git to push into new repo.

Comment: That will work, but it's horrendous. :) There is an feature in git just for that : **forking** (this process is widely documented on GitHub's doc). This way your repository will keep information about its "parent" or upstream repository and you might contribute your changes to the original project easily.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just edit the repository address with `git remote set-url`.

Comment: I tried fork, but it looks like not 'exact' same as the original one. I know it does not make sense, though.

Comment: A fork IS an exact replica, no matter what. If there was anything different, then you must have introduced such change yourself. Or you didn't fork at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may use GitHub Fork function: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Basically, it duplicates the original repo on GitHub.
You can clone, pull, modify, commit, push in this new repo whenever you like.

If you even have to contribute into the original repo as well, you can create pull requests from your forked repo to the original one: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/